# How can I add a euro sign (€) to all tooltips in my chart js line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I've got a line chart that has a tooltip on each data point. The data are prices so I want to add a euro sign before them but this seems harder than it sounds.

My code:

```
const labelsjaar = [
  'jan',
  'feb',
  'mrt',
  'apr',
  'mei',
  'jun',
    'jul',
    'aug',
    'sept',
    'okt',
    'nov',
    'dec',
];
const datajaar = {
  labels: labelsjaar,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Omzet',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(230 0 126)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(230 0 126)',
    data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,177,590.44,801.38,98.62],
  }]
};
Chart.defaults.font.family = 'Panton';
Chart.defaults.font.size = 16;
const configjaar = {
  type: 'line',
  data: datajaar,
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'single',
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
            var i = tooltipItems.index;
            return data.labels[i] + ': ' + data.datasets[0].data[i] + ' €';
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
const myChartjaar = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChartjaar'),
    configjaar
);
```

I found this solution online:

```
tooltips: {
  enabled: true,
  mode: 'single',
  callbacks: {
    label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
        var i = tooltipItems.index;
        return data.labels[i] + ': ' + data.datasets[0].data[i] + ' €';
    }
  }
}
```

But my tooltips remain unchanged, there is no euro sign to be seen.

What am I doing wrong?

A jsfiddle of my chart can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/r4nw91bo/

After the comment below that I was looking at the wrong documentation I tried the following:

```
const labeltext = (tooltipItems) => {
  tooltipItems.forEach(function(tooltipItem) {
    tooltiplabel = '€' + tooltipItem.parsed.y.toLocaleString();
  });
  return tooltiplabel;
};

const configjaar = {
  type: 'line',
  data: datajaar,
  options: {
    plugins:{
      tooltip:{
        callbacks: {
          label: labeltext,
        }
      }
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  }
};
```

But this gives me the error: `tooltipItems.forEach is not a function`. If instead of `label` I use `footer` or `title` it works perfectly, but I don't want to add a title or a footer to my tooltip, I want to replace the existing content with my added `€` sign.

I also tried using their example for adding a dollar sign like this:

```
const configjaar = {
  type: 'line',
  data: datajaar,
  options: {
    plugins:{
      tooltip:{
        callbacks: {
          label: function(context) {
              const label = context.dataset.label || '';

              if (label) {
                  label += ': ';
              }
              if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                  label += new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(context.parsed.y);
              }
              return label;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  }
};
```

But on hover of a data point this gives an error: `Assignment to constant variable.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using V2 syntax in V3, V3 has some major breaking changes over V2. Please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html) for all of them.

For your callback to work you need to define it in `options.plugins.tooltip.callbacks.label`

**EDIT:**

Like the error says you are getting you can't reassign a constant variable since its a constant. If you change it to a `let` it works fine:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(context) {
            let label = context.dataset.label || '';

            if (label) {
              label += ': ';
            }
            if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
              label += new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                style: 'currency',
                currency: 'USD'
              }).format(context.parsed.y);
            }
            return label;
          }
        }
      }
    },
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I still can't get it to work though with the updated documentation. I expanded my original question with what I tried.

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work